# Where are node-gyp's [options] documented?

Tags: node-gyp

`node-gyp --help` says:

```
Usage: node-gyp <command> [options]

where <command> is one of:
 - build - Invokes `make` and builds the module
 - clean - Removes any generated build files and the "out" dir
 - configure - Generates a Makefile for the current module
 - rebuild - Runs "clean", "configure" and "build" all at once
 - install - Install node development files for the specified node version.
 - list - Prints a listing of the currently installed node development files
 - remove - Removes the node development files for the specified version

node-gyp@1.0.2  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
node@1.8.1
```

But where are the `[options]` actually documented? I've picked through various .js source files to try to figure it out and have come up with nothing.

Do `[options]` just pass-thru to gyp?

Specifically, I'm trying to use a bindings file that is not named 'binding.gyp' but it seems like the node -> Python wrapper that sits between node.js and gyp doesn't allow it due to some hard-coding (as best as I can figure out).

For example: `node-gyp configure custom.gyp` produces:

```
<snip>
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp', <-- NOT OK
gyp info spawn args   'custom.gyp', <-- OK
<snip>
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/custom.gypi', <-- MAYBE OK? DON'T LIKE IT BEING GLOBAL (race condition here...)
<snip>
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: <snip>) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error <-- YES because it doesn't exist, I want to use 'custom.gyp'
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
<snip>
```

where `<snip>` just represents me deleting irrelevant information.

Maybe I can get around it by modifying the Python wrapper itself, but is there some other way? Some `node-gyp --option=x` for instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is now quite a bit of documentation for this at the [node-gyp repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#command-options).

Comment: The wiki page of ["binding.gyp" files out in the wild](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/wiki/%22binding.gyp%22-files-out-in-the-wild) was incredibly useful!

Answer (score 2):

Node-gyp is not quite well documented, so statements below are my findings from the project sources.

Options for node-gyp are depended on command. These options are listed in [`configDefs`](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/blob/master/lib/node-gyp.js#L84) object. Some of them are translated into GYP options, others are not.

GYP file name `binding.gyp` is hard-coded in [configure.js](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/blob/master/lib/configure.js#L324)

GYP options probably may be set in `GYP_*` environment variables before node-gyp invocation. Please refer GYP command-line help and [sources](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp/+/master/pylib/gyp/__init__.py), since GYP is not well documented too.

Comment: thanks, so it seems the only way to do this is to intercept the Python script's compilation of the gyp command. I suppose this could be done with a shell intercept that wraps gyp and intercepts the call coming in from node-gyp (to modify it on the way to gyp). That's probably better than modifying the node-gyp command compiler itself as I don't end up with a special version of node-gyp.