# node-gyp errors on protractor installation

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, npm, protractor, node-gyp

I'm attempting to install protractor by running npm install -g protractor and I am getting the following output and I'm not sure if the errors of something of concern. It looks like there is an attempt to install utf-8-validate and bufferutil. After that command, it runs node-gyp rebuild but fails with an MSB8020 error. It references Visual Studio 2010, which I don't have. I have Visual Studio 2012, which is up-to-date.

Microsoft recommends that Visual Studio versions be installed in a particular order, eg: Visual Studio 2010, then Visual Studio 2012, etc.

Before I attempt going through all of that...how important is it that I resolve these errors in order to get a good Protractor setup? Do I really need utf-8-validate and bufferutil?

Other information:

- Windows 8.1
- Node.js v0.12.4
- Python v2.7.3
- Java v1.8.0_45-b14

I hope I have asked this the right way, as this is my first StackExchange question.

Thanks all!

```html
C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming>npm install -g protractor
\
> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-v
alidate
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\seleni
um-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_conf
ig_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..
\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
argets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either
click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC+
+ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 201
0 build tools. [C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build
\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_m
odules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pro
tractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\seleni
um-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_n
ode_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\
node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
argets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either
click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC+
+ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 201
0 build tools. [C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\no
de_modules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\buf
ferutil.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074
:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_m
odules\selenium-webdriver\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\webdriver-manager -> C:\Users\jack\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager
C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor -> C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roam
ing\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor
protractor@2.4.0 C:\Users\jack\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
├── jasminewd@1.1.0
├── jasminewd2@0.0.6
├── html-entities@1.1.3
├── q@1.0.0
├── minijasminenode@1.1.1
├── adm-zip@0.4.4
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── jasmine@2.3.2 (exit@0.1.2, jasmine-core@2.3.4)
├── accessibility-developer-tools@2.6.0
├── saucelabs@1.0.1 (https-proxy-agent@1.0.0)
├── source-map-support@0.2.10 (source-map@0.1.32)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── request@2.57.0 (caseless@0.10.0, aws-sign2@0.5.0, forever-agent@0.6.1, strin
gstream@0.0.4, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, oauth-sign@0.8.0, isstream@0.1.2, json-string
ify-safe@5.0.1, node-uuid@1.4.3, qs@3.1.0, combined-stream@1.0.5, form-data@0.2.
0, mime-types@2.0.14, http-signature@0.11.0, bl@0.9.4, tough-cookie@2.0.0, hawk@
2.3.1, har-validator@1.8.0)
└── selenium-webdriver@2.47.0 (tmp@0.0.24, rimraf@2.4.3, xml2js@0.4.4, ws@0.8.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you may actually be having issues with the build tools being used. Try this:

```
npm install protractor -g --msvs_version=2012
```

That will install with the specific version of the build tools you have access too.

See if that works!

Comment: Yes, that worked! the node-gyp rebuild commands worked without error. I wish I knew the right questions to ask, on how you came to this conclusion. 

But, it seems like my problem would have been avoided if I simply installed VS2010, since your solution forced the install to use 2012. 

How do I learn about the available parameters of npm install? I never knew that --msvs_version= existed. I'm looking at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install for reference

Comment: @TonyKlotz Glad it worked! I've had this issue before, so the answer was quick. If you check your error log, it says that it is attempting to use build tools 2010. I guess it must be a default somewhere, but I just use that to override it. Unfortunately I found this answer through googling as well, not sure where to point you to find all possible commands. --help only shows a few.

Comment: This answer contains a bit about node-gyp and gyp options: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30236700/1355844